# Seg Fault when using addObject to NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, segmentation-fault

I seem to be having a problem with the NSMutableArray.

Here's my code:

```
NSMutableArray *returnArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

while(condition) {
    NSInteger temp = someNumber;
    [returnArray addObject: temp];

}
```

But as soon as it hits the addObject message, the program seg faults. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add primitives like integers to an array, only objects (hence the name addObject:). If you want to add numbers, you have to convert them to an NSNumber, or one of the related classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can only add objects to array and NSInteger is not an array.

```
NSMutableArray *returnArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

while(condition) {
    [returnArray addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt: someNumber]];
}
```

Comment: Or use the new Objective-C syntax: `[returnArray addObject: @(temp)];`

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap primitives such as `NSInteger` into an `NSNumber` class. You can do the following:

```
while(condition)
{
    NSInteger temp = someNumber;
    [returnArray addObject:@(temp)];
}
```

Or if your compiler doesn't support that syntax:

```
while(condition)
{
    NSInteger temp = someNumber;
    [returnArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:temp]];
}
```